# Почему метод не проходит тест?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть такой вот класс и тест не проходит только метод сохранения

```
public class BaseServices<T> : IBaseService<T> where T : BaseEntity, new()

{

    public List<T> AllItem = new List<T>();

    public bool Delete(int id) 
    {
        bool b = false;

        for (int i = AllItem.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (AllItem[i].Id == id)
            {
                AllItem.Remove(AllItem[i]);

                b = true;

                return b;
            }
        }

        return b;
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        T b = null;

        foreach (var a in AllItem)
        {
            if (a.Id == id)
            {
                b = a;
                return b;
            }
        }

        return b;
    }

    public object GetAll() 
    {
        object b = null;

        foreach (var a in AllItem)
        {
            b = a;
            return b;
        }

        return b;
    }

    public bool Save(T entity)
    {
        entity = new T();

        AllItem.Add(entity);

        return true;
    }
}
```

И есть вот такой тест

```
List<AccountModel> Accounts = new List<AccountModel>();

    private BaseServices<AccountModel> AccountBS = new BaseServices<AccountModel>();

    Random rnd = new Random();

    private int SomeId;

    private int AccountsLenth;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Repletion()
    {
        SomeId = rnd.Next(100);

        for (int index = 0; index < 100; ++index)
        {
            AccountBS.AllItem.Add(new AccountModel { Id = index });
        }

        AccountsLenth = Accounts.Count;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetTest()
    {
        AccountModel result = AccountBS.Get(SomeId);

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DeleteBoolTest()
    {
        bool result = AccountBS.Delete(SomeId);

        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SaveBoolTest()
    {
        var ent = new AccountModel();

        bool result = AccountBS.Save(ent);

        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SaveCountTest()
    {
        var ent = new AccountModel();

        AccountBS.Save(ent);

        int AccountsLenth1 = Accounts.Count;

        Assert.AreNotEqual(AccountsLenth, this.Accounts.Count);
    }
}
```

Вот тест метода SaveCountTest не проходит, говорит, что у меня списки пустые

Comment: >>говорит, что у меня списки пустые<< Ну, значит так оно и есть. Вопрос то в чём?

Comment: Вы привели код какими-то отрывками. Скопировал ваш код в студию, чтобы посмотреть что не так - то тут приходится додумывать, то там... Понял, что сейчас допишу и окажется, что у меня тест работает. Давайте вы приведёте полноценный пример для воспроизведения проблемы и тогда будем разговаривать более предметно, а пока лично я - пас.

Comment: Полный код класса добавил

Comment: А можете объяснить в чем смысл аргумента в методе Save? Вы первой же строчкой entity приравниваете новый экземпляр класса и его добавляете, смысл тогда передавать в метод другой экземпляр?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто. Нужно просто внимательно посмотреть, откуда вы берете значения. Вы создаете переменную:

```
List<AccountModel> Accounts = new List<AccountModel>();
```

но вы так ни разу туда ничего и не положили - это просто переменная. Все данные, которые у вас есть, хранятся вот тут:

```
private BaseServices<AccountModel> AccountBS = new BaseServices<AccountModel>();
```

А если быть более точным, то внутри, в `AllItem`. Первое, что нужно переписать:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Repletion()
{
    SomeId = rnd.Next(100);

    for (int index = 0; index < 100; ++index)
    {
        AccountBS.AllItem.Add(new AccountModel { Id = index });
    }

    // уберем количество элементов коллекции отсюда
    // так как в процессе выполнения тестов оно меняется
}
```

Затем сам метод теста переписать следующим образом:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SaveCountTest()
{
    var ent = new AccountModel();

    // присвоим значение в переменную (сколько было до добавления)
    var oldAccountsLenth = AccountBS.AllItem.Count; 

    AccountBS.Save(ent);

    // сравним старое присвоенное значение и новую длину списка
    Assert.AreNotEqual(oldAccountsLenth, AccountBS.AllItem.Count);
}
```

А вот переменную, которая несет не особо много смысловой нагрузки, нужно удалить, я говорю про:

```
List<AccountModel> Accounts = new List<AccountModel>();
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже заметил